# How do I force regex to match the longest possible part of the pattern.

Tags: .net, regex, named-captures

#### I have a pattern  in .net and I want a string be matched with longest possible part of the pattern

```
Pattern : "I (?<a>[\w\W]*)(want to match (?<b>longest))? available"
or "I ((?<a>[\w\W]*)|(want to match (?<b>longest))?)+ available"
```

String : **"I want to match longest available"**

> after match we have : **a="want to match longest" , b=""**
>   but i want : **a="" , b="longest"**

Answer (score 5):

RegEx is "greedy" by default, meaning it will match *as much as possible*.  To make a [repetition lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), add a `?`.

```
I <?a:[\w\W]*?>(want to match <?b:longest>)? available
             ^
```

This will now match 0+ `[\w\W]` characters lazily, or in other words: until the expression can continue to match (once it sees `want to match longest available`, etc).

**Examples:** [greedy](http://regex101.com/r/gT8xY3) vs. [lazy](http://regex101.com/r/lM7eW7) (click 'regex debugger' to see how each of these repetitions operates).

Same idea goes with your other expression, however the greediness is a problem in a different location:

```
I ((?<a>[\w\W]*)|(want to match (?<b>longest))?)+? available
                                                 ^
```

Comment: thanks bu t how about :: I ((?<a>[\w\W]*)|(want to match (?<b>longest))?)+ available

Comment: @AIA this time the greedy culprit is within your entire `((...)|(...))+` expression. You should be able to make that lazy just like in my example: `((...)|(...))+?`